# inconsistency in java thread

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have written a class to check the status of batch API. below is the implementation.

```
//Inner class
private class CallBatchStatus implements Runnable {
    private String batchId;
      
    public CallBatchStatus(String batchId) {
          this.batchId = batchId;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
       getBatchStatus(this.batchId);
    }

 }
```

Similarly, there is one more inner class

```
//Inner class
private class GetBatchStatus {
    private String batchId;
    public GetBatchStatus(String batchID, ExecutorServcie exc){
        this.batchId = batchID;
        exc.execute(new CallBatchStatus(this.batchId));
   }
}
```

and private method in outer class

```
//Recursive Private method call of outer class
private getBatchStatus(String batchId) {
    String response = httpCall(batchId);
    if(!response.equals("COMPLETE")) {
        resposne = getBatchStatus(batchId);
     }
     return response;
}
```

I am executing these threads with the help of executor framework by passing `batchIds` like below:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
List<GetBatchStatus> listOfBatch = batchIds.stream().map(batchId -> new GetBatchStatus(batchId, executorService )).collect(Collector.toList());
```

Let say I am passing two batch ids and it is executing properly but sometimes I am getting the COMPLETE status of the batch which is processing and STARTED status of the batch which already has been executed. I do not understand how the response variable in getBatchStatus is overriding/ exchanging as this is a local variable and running in a different thread.

Comment: What is behind you httpCall method? Also you run() implementation is not valid - how you return status for void method and how you actually collect statuses in the end? Additionally I suggest to convert your recursion to while (!= complete) loop.

Comment: Please provide code that actually compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If GetBatchStatus is an inner class of the outer class CallBatchStatus, when you instantiate it you are implicitly using the same instance of CallBatchStatus so you are having a race condition on the variable CallBatchStatus.batchId.

You would need to use separate instances or copy the value and use a static inner class.